# Equal to or less than not working

Tags: c#

Been at this for an hour I can't see what I'm doing wrong (lol)

```
        // ofDialog settings
        ofDialog.Filter = @"TXT Files|*.txt";
        ofDialog.Title = @"Select linkslist...";
        ofDialog.FileName = "linksList.txt";

        // is cancel pressed?
        if (ofDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        try
        {
            var objReader = new StreamReader(ofDialog.FileName);
            while (objReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                // count the forward slashes
                string haystack = objReader.ReadLine();
                string needle = "/";
                int count = new Regex(Regex.Escape(needle)).Matches(haystack).Count;

                //  3 forward slashes or less add
                if (count <= 3)
                {
                    //Helpers.returnMessage("count=" + count + "equal to=" + 3);
                    // add urls to the listview
                    ListViewItem lv = listViewMain.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(count.ToString());
                }

            }
            Helpers.returnMessage("Job done!");
            // update count

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.returnMessage(ex.Message);
        }
```

I'm trying to count the `"/"` characters, if it's 3 or less add to the ListView, but it's adding some with 4 and more even though I specified: `if (count <= 3)`

Can anyone see my error? :)

Comment: So you say that you enter the `if` block and `count.ToString()` is `"4"`? Sounds impossible.

Comment: Can you post a value of haystack which is failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call `ReadLine()` twice.  So the line you add to your `ListViewMain.Items` is not the same line you checked.

Change

```
ListViewItem lv = listViewMain.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine());
```

to

```
ListViewItem lv = listViewMain.Items.Add(haystack);
```

It is also worth pointing out that you should make use of a using block for the `StreamReader`.

```
using (var objReader = new StreamReader(ofDialog.FileName))
{
  while...
    //Rest of your code here.
}
Helpers.returnMessage("Job done!");
```

This way the stream will dispose when it is finished.  Must avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks mate that was the problem :)